# ¿Como pasar dos parámetros a una api en asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, blazor

Hola comunidad tengo un problema ¿como puedo pasar dos `Id` a una url que va hacia un `endpoint` en el controlador?

en este código obtengo un `id` mediante un `dropdown` y otro `id` lo pongo directamente en una variable ambos id los quiero enviar a la url de la api para realizar un `post` y así guardarlos en una tabla de relación entre clientes y conceptos.

esto esta en la pagina de blazor el guid id lo quiero enviar junto con el id que esta en conceptoselection:

```
private async Task OnSelected(Concepto conceptoSelection)
    {      

        Guid Id = model.Cliente.Id;                   

        var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Concepto",conceptoSelection);
        @if (httpResponse.Error)
        {
            await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeError(await httpResponse.GetBody());
        }
        else
        {
            //await mostrarMensajes.MostrarMensajeExitoso("Concepto Seleccionado");
            navigationManager.NavigateTo("indice-clientes");
        }
    }
```

esto esta en el controlador:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Guid>> Post(ClienteConcepto concepto)
    {
        context.Add(concepto);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return concepto.ClienteId;
    }
```

y esta es la tabla en la cual quiero almacenar esos id:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la clase clienteconcepto:

```
 public class ClienteConcepto
    {
        public Guid ClienteId { get; set; }
        public Guid ConceptoId { get; set; }

        //propiedades de navegacion
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
        public Concepto Concepto { get; set; }
    }
```

clase concepto:

```
public class Concepto
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid id_Conceptos { get; set; }
        public Guid id_Prop { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Tipo de concepto")]
        public TipoDeConcepto Tipo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es requerido")]
        public string Valor { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es requerido")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; } 
        public bool Activo { get; set; }
        public List<ClienteConcepto> ClienteConcepto { get; set; }
    }
    public enum TipoDeConcepto : int
    {
        [Display(Name = "Metodo de pago")]
        MetodoPago,
        [Display(Name = "Forma de pago")]
        FormaPago,
        [Display(Name = "Uso del CFDI")]
        UsoCFDI,
        [Display(Name = "Directorio del certificado")]
        CERT_DIR,
        [Display(Name = "Directorio de la llave (Key)")]
        KEY_DIR,
        [Display(Name = "Directorio")]
        DIR,
        [Display(Name = "Reporte")]
        Reporte,
        //inserte mas 
    }
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega las clases `Concepto` y `ClienteConcepto` por favor :D

Comment: ya agregue las dos clases

Comment: No sabes como pasar los dos parametros en la URI para que la API lo reciba o no sabes como tomar el valor del componente?

Comment: no se como pasar los dos id a la url que va hacia la api para mandarlos a un endpoint en el controlador y de ahí guardarlos en la base de datos, se supone que post solo toma dos argumentos la url y el contenido que se va enviar, pero aquí yo estoy mandando dos id y por lo tanto no se pueden enviar

Comment: Si entendi bien lo que quieres es pasarle un id a la url de esta manera /MiUrl/Id ?

Comment: var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Concepto",conceptoSelection);                aqui en conceptoselection ya va in id_concepto que obtengo en un dropdown y parte quiero enviarle otro id que seria id_cliente, pero esa url hacia la api solo toma dos argumentos y ya no me acepta otro id para mandarlo

Comment: var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Concepto",conceptoSelection, ID); esto ya no es valido solo puedo enviar una url y un contenido en el post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si entendí bien lo que quieres es pasarle un id directamente a la url, mas no al cuerpo de la petición. El nombre que se le asigna dentro del verbo http tiene coincidir con el nombre en la firma del metodo.

```
[HttpPost("{id}")]
public ActionResult<T> MiMetodo(int id)
```

Tambien puedes anadir reglas a la varible dentro del verbo http, para evitar problemas de ambigüedad.

```
[HttpPost("{id:int}")]
public ActionResult<T> MiMetodo(int id)

[HttpPost("{id:int:min(5)}")]
public ActionResult<T> MiMetodo(int id)

[HttpPost("{id:int:max(5)}")]
public ActionResult<T> MiMetodo(int id)

[HttpPost("{id:int:range(0, 5)}")]
public ActionResult<T> MiMetodo(int id)

[HttpPost("{id:guid}")]
public ActionResult<T> MiMetodo(guid id)
```

Y si son N cantidad de ids simplemente

```
[HttpPost("{primerId:int}/{segundoId:int}/...")]
public ActionResult<T> MiMetodo(int primerId, int segundoId)
```

---

Lo que quieres se puede hacer de dos formas.

```
[HttpPost("{clienteId:guid}/{conceptoId:guid}")]
public IActionResult MiMetodo(guid clienteId, guid conceptoId)
{
    var clienteConcepto = new ClienteConcepto
    {
         ConceptoId = conceptoId,
         ClienteId = clienteId,
    }

    context.Add(clienteConcepto);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
```

Como veo que quieres hacer la peticion de manera interna, la otra forma seria usando `HttpClient`, y pasandole un `diccionario` con los campos del objeto que quieres crear y .net se encarga de hacer la conversion de `diccionario` a `Clase<T>`..

Comment: si entiendo lo que me explicas pero eso seria mas bien si quisiera filtrar o buscar por id no? por que por ejemplo si lo hago de esa forma en la propiedad add no me tomara dos argumentos para agregar :

Comment: [HttpPost("{primerId:guid}/{segundoId:guid}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(Guid primerId, Guid segundoId)
        {
            context.Add(primerId,segundoId);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();}

Comment: revisa de nuevo.

Comment: ok ya entendi mejor como estructurar el endponit pero del lado del cliente como envio la url y el content que esta esperando post :

Comment: var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Concepto",conceptoSelection); en esta linea ya que no acepta conceptoselection,Id solo puedo poner un solo content

Comment: quedaria algo asi como te dije, var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Concepto/clienteId/conceptoId");

Comment: quedaria algo asi como te dije, var httpResponse = await repositorio.Post("api/Concepto/clienteId/conceptoId"); realmente no se de blazor :S

Comment: de igual manera muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda , me diste una idea de como crear el post del lado del servidor ahora solo me falta del lado del cliente

Comment: muchas gracias puse tu respuesta pero la puse del lado del cliente en vez de ponerlo en el controlador y funciono , marcare tu respuesta como aceptada ya que si la utilice